# How to execute node.js script by using .bat file?

Tags: node.js, batch-file

I want to execute this script `pm2 start d:\nodejs\ecosystem.config.js` using .bat file
(I'm on windows 10)

but when I execute .bat file, it didn't work

I can't find any clues on any web, google

Comment: node "d:\nodejs\ecosystem.config.js"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
node d:\nodejs\ecosystem.config.js
```

Above command should execute the javascript file if the node is installed in the PC.